# Match and Encrypt Few Chars in Word

Tags: php

I am developing a screening logic where complete text of content to be matched with list of keywords in php via regular expression.
I am using the following code which match words properly and make it bold.

```
$pattern = "/mango|apple|banana/";
$text = "i like banana and apple alot";
$replacement = "<strong>$0</strong>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

this code properly match and make matched word enclosed in strong like

```
i like <strong>banana</strong> and <strong>apple</strong> alot.
```

But i want to replace banana as

```
b****a and apple as a****e
```

instead of making it bold.

Can anyone help me how it will be possible.

Comment: are all words length = 6 ?

Comment: not its dynamic depend on keyword.

Comment: use @Rocket Hazmat's answer its what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_replace`.

```
preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
    $str = $matches[0];
    $len = strlen($str);
    $stars = str_repeat('*', $len-2);
    return $str[0].$stars.$str[$len-1];
}, $text);
```

*Updated to create a dynamic number of stars*

Comment: This would give  a fixed number of "stars".

Comment: @MikeBrant: Yes it would.  That's what his question showed.  If he wants to *not* do that, he could use `str_repeat` to create the correct number.  I updated my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

If your patterns are fixed, you might want to pass arrays to `preg_replace` like this:

```
$patterns = array(
    '/mango/',
    '/apple/',
    '/banana/'
}
$replacements = array(
    'm***o',
    'a***e',
    'b****a'
)
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```

This would also be applicable to any given array of keywords you want to replace like this:

```
$keywords; // array populated with key words
$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();
array_walk($keywords, function($value, $key) {
    $patterns[] = '/' . $value . '/';
    $replacements[] = strpad($value[0], strlen($value) - 1, '*') . $value[strlen($value) - 1];
}
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```